# getView method of baseAdapter is not getting called

Tags: android, android-spinner, baseadapter

I have a spinner view . i set its adapter as customAdapter which extends base adapter.
But the get view method of adapter is not getting called. `

```
 public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private TextView mLine1, mLine2;

    private String mEmptyString = "--";

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context) {
        super();


        mContext = context;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return view;

    }}
```

and then i am setting the adapter by setAdapter().

Comment: show us how do you set your adapter

Answer (score 1):

For spinners you need to implement getDropDownView(), it is a speciall method called for DropDowns...

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the getView() function correctly:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_single_spinner_row, null);
    }

    ... do whatever with the convertView (convertView.findViewById(...))...

    return convertView;

}
```